# In Rails 3, how can I render a partial template to a variable in my model, while also passing local variables into the template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I'm doing some email templating in Rails which seems to be a common use case for rendering templates into variables in a model.  How can I go about this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Model should know nothing about presentation. Try setting a variable and then rendering partial inside email template instead.

Comment: This doesn't help at all.  What if I need to generate emails from the template and send in the background with CRON?

Comment: You can use ERB templating engine in the scripts, but the logic shouldn't be in your "model" side of the app.

Comment: What logic shouldn't be in the "model" side of my app?  I have an email template that needs to be filled based on some calculations.  These calculations and template population needs to happen dynamically in the background process that sends email.  So I think that if anything, the template should exist in the model side of my code and all of the logic to populate it should go there.